# Why declare Perl variable with "my" at file scope?

Tags: perl, scope

I'm learning Perl and trying to understand variable scope. I understand that `my $name = 'Bob';` will declare a local variable *inside a sub*, but why would you use the `my` keyword at the global scope? Is it just a good habit so you can safely move the code into a sub?

I see lots of example scripts that do this, and I wonder why. Even with `use strict`, it doesn't complain when I remove the `my`. I've tried comparing behaviour with and without it, and I can't see any difference.

Here's [one example](http://perlmaven.com/simple-database-access-using-perl-dbi-and-sql) that does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbfile = "sample.db";

my $dsn      = "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile";
my $user     = "";
my $password = "";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {
   PrintError       => 0,
   RaiseError       => 1,
   AutoCommit       => 1,
   FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
});

# ...

$dbh->disconnect;
```

### Update

It seems I was unlucky when I tested this behaviour. Here's the script I tested with:

```
use strict;

my $a = 5;
$b = 6;

sub print_stuff() {
    print $a, $b, "\n"; # prints 56
    $a = 55;
    $b = 66;
}

print_stuff();
print $a, $b, "\n"; # prints 5566
```

As I learned from some of the answers here, `$a` and `$b` are special variables that are already declared, so the compiler doesn't complain. If I change the `$b` to `$c` in that script, then it complains.

As for why to use `my $foo` at the global scope, it seems like the *file* scope may not actually be the *global* scope.

Comment: As a general rule, always use tight variable scope, and move it gradually outside as you need it (when it should be available from various parts of your program).

Comment: You are mistaken: Perl *will* raise an error under `use strict` if you don't declare a variable at any scope, including the outermost. The exception is `$a` and `$b` which are predeclared for use in `sort`, which is why they should be avoided for your own use (apart from being very poor identifiers).

Comment: Ah , @Borodin, I think I used `$a` in my test. I will confirm on Monday. If that's the case, it answers my question.

Comment: `my` doesn't really have anything to do with `sub`. `my` can be used to declare a variable within a `sub`, but it can also be used to declare a variable within a `for` loop, or an `if` block, or any other lexical scope. Basically, stop thinking that variable scopes are in any way tied to subs. This isn't Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just good practice. As a personal rule, I try to keep variables in the smallest scope possible. If a line of code can't see a variable, then it can't mess with it in unexpected ways.

I'm surprised that you found that the script worked under `use strict` without the `my`, though. That's generally not allowed:

```
$ perl -E 'use strict; $db = "foo"; say $db'
Global symbol "$db" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$db" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
$ perl -E 'use strict; my $db = "foo"; say $db'
foo
```

Variables `$a` and `$b` are exempt:

```
$ perl -E 'use strict; $b = "foo"; say $b'
foo
```

But I don't know how you would make the code you posted work with strict and a missing `my`.

Comment: Only `$a` and `$b` (which are special inside a `sort` call) are exempt.

Answer (score 4):

The addition of `my` was about the best thing that ever happened to Perl and the problem it solved was typos.

Say you have a variable `$variable`. You do some assignments and comparisons on this variable.

```
$variable = 5;

# intervening assignments and calculations...

if ( $varable + 20 > 25 ) # don't use magic numbers in real code
{
    # do one thing
}
else
{
    # do something else
}
```

Do you see the subtle bug in the above code that happens if you don't `use strict;` and require variables be declared with `my`? The `# do one thing` case will *never* happen. I encountered this several times in production code I had to maintain.

Comment: +1 LOL I never thought of it quite that way - it's like "advanced" (errm or "in advance") spell-checking for variable names ...

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

- `strict` demands that all variables be declared with a `my` (or `state`) or installed into the package--declared with an `our` statement or a `use vars` pragma (archaic), or inserted into the symbol table at compile time.
- They are *that file's* variables. They remain of no concern and no use to any module required during the use of that file.
- They can be used across packages (although that's a less good reason.)
- Lexical variables don't have any of the magic that the only alternative does. You can't "push" and "pop" a lexical variable as you change scope, as you can with any package variable. No magic means faster and plainer handling.
- Laziness. It's just easier to declare a `my` with no brackets as opposed to concentrating its scope by specific bracketing.

  ```
  {   my $visible_in_this_scope_only;
      ...
      sub bananas {
          ...
          my $bananas = $visible_in_this_scope_only + 3;
          ...
      }
  } # End $visible_in_this_scope_only
  ```

(Note on the syntax: in my code, I never use a bare brace. It will always tell you, either before (standard loops) or after what the scope is for, even if it would have been "obvious".

Answer (score 2):

A `sub`  controls/limits the scope of variables between the braces `{}` that define its operations. Of course many variables exist outside of a particular function and using lexical `my` for "global" variables can give you more control over how "dynamic" their behavior is inside your application. The `Private Variables via my()` section of `perlodoc`[`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) discusses reasons for doing this pretty thoroughly.

I'm going to quote myself from [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23222857/2019415) which is not the best thing to do on SO but here goes:

> The classic **perlmonks** node - [Variable Scoping in Perl: the
>   basics](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677) - is a frequently
>   consulted reference :-)

As I noted in a comment, Bruce Gray's talk at YAPC::NA 2012 - [The why of my()](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA4mUs3Ro98) is a good story about how a pretty expert perl programmer wrapped his head around perl and namespaces.

I've heard people explain `my` as Perl's equivalent to Javascript's `var` - it's practically necessary but, Perl being `perl`, things will work without it if you insist or take pains to make it do that.

ps: Actually with Javascript, I guess functions **are** used to control "scope" in a way that is analagous to your description of using `my` in `sub`'s.